# Why doesn't this style inherit?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I have this html

```
<table class="actList">
    <tr>
        <th> a </th> <th> a </th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> a </td> <td> a </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this css

```
.actList { 
   background-color: rgb(235, 239, 249); 
   width: 100%;
}

th.activity, th.actList { 
   text-align: left; 
   font-weight: normal; 
   padding: 0.4em 1em 0.4em 0.3em; 
}
```

Then I would expect that the last line means, that all `<th>`'s in the table with `class="actList"` would get this style. But it doesn't as seen here

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/k3Bv5/

What would the proper CSS for `th.actList` look like?

Can it be done without adding a class to each `<th>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

th.actList means any th elements with the class of actList.

In your example only the table element has this class. Classes don't inherit!

what I suspect you are after is

```
.actlist th {...}
```

Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/k3Bv5/3/

Comment: Very intersting. What is the difference of `th.actList` and just `.actList`? I assume in both cases I need to have a `class="actList"` in each <th>?

Comment: th.actList will just select <th> marked with "actList" class. .actList will select any element marked with "actList" class.

Comment: If you want to select some <th> elements, and not others, then yes - you will need to define a class on them.

Comment: Ok, so that means I can have elements with `class="actList"` without applying a style to them.

Comment: Yes - that's right. If for instance you had two types of <TH> element - class1 and class2, and you wanted all TH elements to be styled the same, but the <TD> elements within them to be styled differently then you'd have th {...}, th.class1 td {...} and th.class2 td {...}

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine you are trying to target `th`s within the `.actlist` in which case you need: `.actlist th` as your CSS selector, see fiddle below:

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3Bv5/4/)

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `.actList` on `<table>`, so your CSS should be `table.actList th`

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting: I suggest you also look up CSS specificity. See -- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 2):

`th.actList` means "A `th` that is a member of `actList`"

You want: "A `th` that is a [descendent](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_descendant.htm) of a member of `actList`"

```
.actList th
```

Answer (score 1):

Change: `th.activity, th.actList { text-align: left; font-weight: normal; padding: 0.4em 1em 0.4em 0.3em; }`

```
To: th.activity, .actList th { text-align: left; font-weight: normal; padding: 0.4em 1em 0.4em 0.3em; }
```

`th.actList` means that this rule will apply to th elements that have class="actList". You want to apply rule to th elements inside "actList" class, so for that you need `.actList th`

Answer (score 1):

Currently none of your `th` tags have the `.actList` class applied to them.

If you want to target `th`'s inside a table with class `.actList` then you can simply do:

```
.actList th{ /* styles */}
```